# Can the Microsoft Office Ribbon be coded into a non-Office desktop application?

Tags: vb.net, ribbon

Can the Microsoft Office Ribbon be coded into a non-Office Windows Forms application for VB? If so, how?

I searched both here and on Google, but found only topics related to Office apps and add-ins, and nothing regarding non-Office use.

Comment: Office Ribbon seems to be not much more than an Office solution. However, WPF has a ribbon control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon?view=net-5.0 and here is an interesting WinForms project: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application

Comment: Windows forms, WPF or something else? Search for "[NameOfFramework] Ribbon Control". I just found a bunch of winforms projects

Comment: for standard winforms - no, there is a not a native control. However, a nice open source project exists here: https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms

Comment: Ah, I was only looking at Windows Forms apps. But perhaps I can use this as a focus to delve into WPF; I've never used it before. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon?view=net-5.0) class from the .net framework (WPF) for creating a similar UI in your applications. Office applications don't share the UI for others.

Comment: Yes, as long as you point out the HUGE WHOPPER ELEPHANT in the room - not for winforms.

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to host WPF controls in a WinForms app with an `ElementHost` adapter.

Comment: Thank you.  I've only used Windows Forms. But perhaps I can use this as a focus to delve into WPF.

Comment: Thanks Eugene - I not tested that idea - but if hosting WPF controls can be done with relative ease, then I stand corrected. As noted, in the first post here, I link to a open source ribbon for winforms. Not sure which road is a better choice.